# What techniques are there for character isolation given a image containing a text?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, ocr

For example suppose you are given image with white background and black text. I am trying to find a way to separate each character in the word, maybe just a bounding rectangle for each character is enough. I hope its clear enough, else I can post example. Any techniques out there, didn't find much in google yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) training command for making box files, the output file will contain the coordinates of the bounding box for each character.

```
tesseract someimage.tif output batch.nochop makebox
```